# Safe publication of array/collection/map contents written once

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, guava, immutability

**Main question:**
What is the best way to perform safe publication of the contents of an array, collection, or map in Java?

Here is what I've tried and some side questions I have:

---

**Side question #1**

On thread 1, I'm writing to an [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key, value);
```

My current understanding is that:

- [`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) does not constitute safe publication of the references stored in the map.
- By examining [these particular implementations of `Map.of()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9ab387d14e8c160d5dac79c291fdfc79c2f912bc/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Map.java#L1279-L1329), the result of:

  - [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of()) could be documented as thread-safe.
  - [`Map.of(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V)) could be documented as thread-safe.
  - [`Map.of(key1, value1, key2, value2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V)) and beyond could not be documented as thread-safe.

Am I wrong?

---

**Side question #2**

Now, I want to safely publicate the contents of an [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) which is written to before it is read from.
My current understanding is that using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) would incur a performance penalty, therefore I would prefer to avoid using it in a scenario like this one.

I came up with this alternative:

```
class MapSafePublication<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    private final ThreadLocal<Map<K, V>> safeMap = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
        synchronized (MapSafePublication.this) {
            return new HashMap<>(map);
        }
    });

    synchronized void write(K key, V value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    V read(K key) {
        return safeMap.get().get(key);
    }
}
```

Is it correct? Are there better ways to do this?

---

**Side question #3**

On thread 1, I'm writing to a volatile array:

```
volatile Object[] array = new Object[size];
array[index] = value;
```

My current understanding is that reading `array[index]` from another thread isn't safe.
To make it safe, one has to use [`AtomicReferenceArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html).

Here is an excerpt from [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

```
final transient Object lock = new Object();
private transient volatile Object[] array;

public E set(int index, E element) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Object[] es = getArray();
        E oldValue = elementAt(es, index);

        if (oldValue != element) {
            es = es.clone();
            es[index] = element;
        }
        // Ensure volatile write semantics even when oldvalue == element
        setArray(es);
        return oldValue;
    }
}

public E get(int index) {
    return elementAt(getArray(), index);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <E> E elementAt(Object[] a, int index) {
    return (E) a[index];
}
```

How can [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#get(int)) read from the array safely, if it doesn't acquire the same lock that was used by [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#set(int,E))?

The same applies to the result of [`com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf()`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf-java.util.Collection-), which as per my current understanding, does not constitute safe publication of the references stored in or returned by the parameter object. Am I wrong?

---

**Clarification #1**

From a memory visibility perspective, which of the following are safe?

```
class Test<K, V> {
    private final Test1<K, V> test1;
    private Test2<K, V> test2;

    Test(Test1<K, V> test1, Test2<K, V> test2) {
        this.test1 = test1;
        this.test2 = test2;
    }

    void test(K key) {
        System.out.println(test1.read(key));
        System.out.println(test2.read(key));
    }
}

class Test1<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    void write(K key, V value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    V read(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}

class Test2<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    void write(K key, V value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    V read(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}

// Thread 1
Test1<K, V> test1 = new Test1<>();
test1.write(key, value);
Test2<K, V> test2 = new Test2<>();
test2.write(key, value);

// Thread 2
Test<K, V> test = new Test<>(test1, test2);
test.test(key);
```

---

**Clarification #2:**

Consider the following example:

```
// Thread 1
Object obj = new Object();
volatile Object object = obj;

// Thread 2
System.out.println(object);

// Thread 1 or 3
object = obj;

// Thread 2
System.out.println(object);
```

So in the latter case, there is no happens-before relationship between the reader and writer threads?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @AndyTurner I believe my concerns are related to a single topic and therefore can be addressed in a single answer. Moreover, those are only examples; I would prefer a generic, detailed answer over a quick solution, also because I could not find any on this site.

Comment: Please can you provide a link to your source for `CopyOnWriteArrayList.set`? Your excerpt has very different semantics to, say, [this version](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#L408).

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm using [Zulu Community 11.35.13 on Windows](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&version=java-11-lts&os=&os=windows&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk). I simplified the source for brevity's sake, which may not have been a good idea, so now I've updated it.

Comment: when you say "safe publication", it usually means via the constructor, is that what you mean? otherwise, any truly (deep) immutable holder would count as such, I guess.

Comment: @Eugene To make the contents of the array/collection/map visible from other threads after it has been populated, possibly with thread-safety guarantees that would reduce the amount of work required to make the elements themselves thread-safe. How the reference to the array/collection/map is published, either via `final` or `volatile` field or through locking, is redundant.

Comment: Possibly with thread safe guaranty? If you could clearly explain what you want to achieve, this would be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @Eugene I want to populate an array/collection/map from one thread, and then access it from other threads. I wouldn't say I am taking a snapshot, because that often involves copying, which I would want to avoid if possible. If the solution gives additional guarantees (such as happens-before relationships) that will aid in ensuring the thread-safety of the stored objects, then that will be great, but is not a requirement, only a consideration.

Comment: I might be missing something, but this is still vague ( at least for me ). You want to populate the array in one thread and _then_ have the guarantee that the other thread reading this array... Has what guarantees? That all elements written are read, meaning the entire array is fully visible? Or it allows seeing partial array elements? Its all about details here.

Comment: @Eugene Write to the array once in one thread, and then make both the array and its contents fully visible from other threads.

Comment: The new example is pointless, there is no modification after publication, so it doesn’t matter whether there is a happens-before relationship between the redundant write and the read. Besides that, you are writing the actions of the threads interleaved as if the order was under control. But there is no such control over the timing. If the first `System.out.println(object);` is executed before the first write to `object`, there is no happens-before relationship. Even the second `System.out.println(object);` could be executed before the first write to `object`.

Comment: @Holger I believe it does matter whether or not there is a happens-before relationship, because the effect is not limited to `object` itself, but also to all preceding actions. Also, I understand that the order of execution may be different, however I am interested in the semantics of `volatile`, and whether there is a happens-before relationship when re-reading after a redundant write of the same object.

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani to understand whether you have a happens-before relationship, you have to understand the implication of the unspecified execution timing. When there is nothing that guarantees you that the volatile read is performed after the volatile write (and you can’t even check the situation because the write was redundant), there is no happens-before relationship. That’s precisely the error I highlighted regarding the `oldvalue == element` scenario. Even when running on a JVM trying to enforce the write semantic, the program relying on it still would be broken.

Comment: While it may be self-serving, I suggest you read _Java Concurrency in Practice_ and then come back and ask some more specific questions?

Answer (score 4):

There is no “best way to perform safe publication”, as the decision for a way of publication depends on the actual use case involving publication.

So it’s not correct to say that `Collections.unmodifiableMap(…)` is not a safe publication. This method isn’t a publication at all.

When a thread is potentially modifying data after an object’s publication, i.e. when another thread may already processing the data, there is no safe publication at all.

A `ConcurrentHashMap` may solve this issue not because it makes the publication of the map safe, but because each modification is a safe publication on its own. This still only makes its use thread safe if the using threads can cope with the fact that no consistent overall state of the map exists when there are modifications while the map is processed, but only individual mappings are consistent. And, each key or value *must not* be modified after publication.

When you obey the rule that you must not modify the object(s) after publication, there are tons of possibilities of correct publication. Consider:

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(42);
map.put("foo", l);

Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(map);
    }
};
t.start();
System.out.println(map);
t.join();
```

There is a *happens-before* relationship between the call `t.start()` and any action performed by the thread. This is sufficient for a safe publication of the `HashMap` and the contained `ArrayList` without any additional effort—as long as we obey the “no modification after publication” rule. The fact that both threads may read the map concurrently doesn’t matter.

So when you have code like

```
volatile Object[] array = new Object[size];
array[index] = value;
```

you are right, it is not safe because it violates the “no modification after publication” rule.

But the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is different, when you look at the posted code closely:

```
public E set(int index, E element) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Object[] es = getArray();
        E oldValue = elementAt(es, index);

        if (oldValue != element) {
            es = es.clone(); // <- create a local copy
            es[index] = element; // <- modifies the copy that has not been published
        }
        // Ensure volatile write semantics even when oldvalue == element
        setArray(es); // <- publishes the copy
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

So there’s no violation of the “no modification after publication” rule, as modifications are always performed an local copies before publishing them and the `volatile` writes of an entirely new array reference are establishing a *happens-before* relationship with subsequent `volatile` reads of this reference. The `synchronized` only exists to make multiple modifications consistent.

Note that the code you’ve posted differs in some regard from the [this OpenJDK implementation](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#L408):

```
public E set(int index, E element) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Object[] es = getArray();
        E oldValue = elementAt(es, index);

        if (oldValue != element) {
            es = es.clone();
            es[index] = element;
            setArray(es);
        }
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

While both work without problems when being used correctly, the difference

```
        // Ensure volatile write semantics even when oldvalue == element
        setArray(es); // invoked even when oldvalue == element
```

shows a wrong mindset exactly hitting the discussed rule. When `oldvalue == element`, the element being set was already in the list, in other words, already published. So if the element was modified before this redundant `set` call, it would violate the “no modification after publication” rule and performing another `volatile` write here wouldn’t fix that. On the other hand, if no modification was made, the `volatile` write would be obsolete. So there is no reason to perform the `volatile` write when `oldvalue == element`.

This may help you evaluating your `ThreadLocal` approach. There is no point in creating a new copy for every thread. Since these copies are never modified, they can be read by an arbitrary number of threads safely. But since these snapshots are never modified, no thread will ever notice changes that are made to the original map after its snapshot has been created. If changes happen rarely and you have a lot of readers, a similar approach to `CopyOnWriteArrayList` would work.

Comment: 1+, the question is vague, at best, IMO. especially since "safe publication" is usually targeted towards constructors.

Comment: @Eugene well, as I tried to explain, safe publication precludes subsequent modifications, so it’s always the sequence “object creation” → optional additional setup (like populating collections) → publication, only the time between may differ. So “publication after constructing” is a natural topic.

Comment: I understand that doing `volatile Map<K, V> safeMap = map;` after `map` has been modified, constitutes safe publication of the references stored in `map`. And if I wanted to avoid paying the price of a volatile read, would `final Map<K, V> safeMap = map;` be enough to establish a happens-before relationship?

Comment: My understanding is that the difference between the two implementations is that in the former, a happens-before relationship on which the caller may be relying would not be established when `oldValue == element`. However that would involve the caller relying on implementation details, which is wrong. Anyway, here are the [source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/943b87ddde7f85f5f822662fe0a03538673eb2a8/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#L417-L418) and the [commit](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/9f5e9b5b5fe46399795c93cf7ecf87731ccbebd0).

Comment: There is no happens-before relationship in either implementation when `oldValue == element`. A happens-before relationship has two ends and the other end, a reading thread, can’t tell apart the situation before the redundant set operation and after, since it doesn’t change anything. Since getting the element does not guaranty that the second set operation has happened at all, you can’t assume a happens-before relationship. It’s a bit surprising seeing who made the commit as he should know better.

Comment: A `final Map<K, V> safeMap = map;` must happen in a constructor and a `static final Map<K, V> safeMap = map;` must happen in a class initializer. In the latter case, you don’t even need the `final` as the class initialization provides its own guaranty. In the former case, the field is member of an object and the publication of that object is crucial. When the containing object is properly published, you don’t need `final` too. The `final` modifier can provide additional guarantees in the case of a racy publication which is rarely needed. “No subsequent modification” still is the key here…

Comment: Also from [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/TSM03-J.+Do+not+publish+partially+initialized+objects): _The JMM guarantees that the fully initialized values of fields that are declared `final` are safely published to every thread that reads those values at some point no earlier than the end of the object's constructor._ seems to be in contrast with _When the containing object is properly published, you don’t need `final` too._

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani how do you conclude from the presence of a certain guaranty for `final` fields that there is no guaranty for non-`final` fields? Does “airplanes can fly” imply that birds can not? A properly published object implies the correct publication of the entire object’s state, if set up before the publication (which is what “no modification after publication” implies). `final` fields provide guarantees even in scenarios where the object has not published correctly (but after the constructor). But this shouldn’t invite to exploiting incorrect publications.

Comment: So writing to a non-`final` map from one thread, before reading from the same map from another thread, is safe even if both threads were started in the past?

Comment: *When the containing object is properly published*. In other words, the correct publication of the object is the construct that establishes the happens-before relationship. As you just said yourself in the other comment: “*…because the effect is not limited to object itself, but also to all preceding actions*”. It doesn’t matter when the thread has been started, what matters, is how you publish the object containing the `map` field to the thread.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first part:

> Collections.unmodifiableMap() does not constitute safe publication of the references stored in the map.

Correct.

> By examining the implementation of Map.of() ...

The only place to examine is the Javadoc. If it does not describe any thread safety guarantees, there are no reliable guarantees. The implementations could be changed either to make things "thread safe", or to remove thread safety.

---

To answer your third part:

> How can get() read from the array safely, if it doesn't acquire the same lock that was used by set()?

The semantics of `volatile` are such that a write to a volatile field [happens before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) a read of that volatile field.

So, this simplified sequence of actions in `set`:

```
Object[] es = getArray() /* volatile read of array (not especially relevant) */;
es = es.clone();
es[index] = element;
setArray(es);  // Internally does `array = es;`, so a volatile write.
```

happens before this, in `get`.

```
return elementAt(getArray() /* volatile read of array */, index);
```

As such, the updated array element is visible to threads calling `get`.

The `synchronized` isn't really relevant to that. that's really there to ensure that two threads aren't updating the array at the same time; this creates its own happens-before (between multiple invocations of `set`), but these are separate from the happens-before between the volatile write and read.

Comment: I understand that one must not rely on implementation details, however are my statements regarding the current implementation of `Map.of()` correct?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani There is no single definition of either "the" or "current" in terms of implementation of a particular class or method.

Comment: I've included a link to the source I am referring to.

Comment: So, doing `volatile Map<K, V> safeMap = map;` after `map` has been modified, constitutes safe publication of the references stored in `map`? Also what if `final` is used instead of `volatile`?